# Refresh tableView appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to refresh tableView appearance after I press "Dark mode".But it looks like this:

**Before press"Dark mode"**

[image: Before press"Dark mode"]

**After press"Dark mode"**

[image: After press"Dark mode"]
How can I refresh this tableView after I changed it's appearance

Mycode:

```
@IBAction func setDarkMode(sender: UISwitch) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay:0,options:UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState,  animations: { () -> Void in
        self.setStyleMode()
    }) { (finish: Bool) -> Void in
    }
}
func setStyleMode() {
    if isDarkMode {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.1922, green:0.1922, blue:0.1922, alpha:1.0)
        self.tableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.1922, green:0.1922, blue:0.1922, alpha:1.0)
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.3137, green:0.3137, blue:0.3137, alpha:1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.1451, green:0.1451, blue:0.1451, alpha:1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red:0.6549, green:0.6549, blue:0.6549, alpha:1.0)]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.9412, green:0.3412, blue:0.302, alpha:1.0)
        for sectionIndex in 0...tableView.numberOfSections - 1 {
            for rowIndex in 0...tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(sectionIndex) - 1 {
                let cellPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowIndex, inSection: sectionIndex)
                let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellPath)
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.1451, green:0.1451, blue:0.1451, alpha:1.0)
            }
        }
        for aLabel in labels {
            aLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:0.6549, green:0.6549, blue:0.6549, alpha:1.0)
        }
        
    } else {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.9529, green:0.9529, blue:0.9529, alpha:1.0)
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.7372, green:0.7371, blue:0.7372, alpha:1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.9412, green:0.3412, blue:0.302, alpha:1.0)
        for sectionIndex in 0...tableView.numberOfSections - 1 {
            for rowIndex in 0...tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(sectionIndex) - 1 {
                let cellPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowIndex, inSection: sectionIndex)
                let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellPath)
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                //do stuff with 'cell'
            }
        }
        for aLabel in labels {
            aLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
    }
}
```

(This "settings" tableView is in a "tableviewController " and embed in a ContainerView)

Comment: How are you controlling / supplying the section headers? You just aren't doing anything to them.

Comment: also, you haven't said exactly which part you're unhappy with so everyone here is guessing...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have not called `reloadData()`

Once your style changes are over call call execute the following code

tableView.reloadData()

Another thing is, styling your `tableViewCell`should be done inside

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Not inside `setStyleMode()` function. You can make the style changes based on some bool value.

Hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: It's fine to edit the cell outside row at index path, you don't need to reload the table in this case

Comment: Yeah , that is right , but

 'for rowIndex in 0...tableView.numberOfRowsInSectio'  is every single cell is lot more than what is enough. If the number of cells are less , editing cells outside is ok

Comment: it's a guess, but i'm expecting the table view is a static list of cells in this case

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the cell's background color, but not the cell's `contentView`'s background color.

You should do:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellPath)
cell?.backgroundColor = ....
cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = ....
```

You might have to dig deeper if your cell has more wrapper views in the hierarchy.

A couple of observations, though:

1. It would be a better pattern to define a method within the `UITableViewCell` subclass to define a dark and light mode. In complex cell structures, you might not easily be able to access all the subviews you need. Besides, what about encapsulation?
2. I would also much prefer the reload way. Calling a `UITableViewDatasource` method manually seems like an anti-pattern.
3. There's a lot of duplication in your code. You could significantly reduce the dependency by, for instance, using ternary operators on `isDarkMode`

Answer (score 0):

Need change background of "headerView" and "footerView" in "setStyleMode()"

```
let header = tableView.headerViewForSection(sectionIndex)
let footer = tableView.footerViewForSection(sectionIndex)
header?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.1922, green:0.1922, blue:0.1922, alpha:1.0)
footer?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.1922, green:0.1922, blue:0.1922, alpha:1.0)
```